# C# method running with worksheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, methods

Maybe it is a beginner question but I can not seem to figure it out. How do I run the method as seen in the picture?

[[image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QlnL.png][1]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8967612).

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You are not calling the method passing the required parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your picture your code for the ExcelRun may not be in the same class or linked to the class where you are trying to run it.

Example to get it to work:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExcelRun();
        Bogo.excelRun2();
        Bogo n = new Bogo();
        n.excelRun3();
    }

    private void ExcelRun()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Have the Method Available in the same Class or callable from another."); 
    }
}

public class Bogo
{

    public static void excelRun2()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello there");
    }

    public void excelRun3()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I am here");
    }
}
```

This tutorial might help:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm